curl: (77) error setting certificate file: elasticsearch-8.13.4/config/certs/http_ca.crt
Im following the instructions from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.13/targz.html and im getting this error when i run
curl --cacert elasticsearch-8.13.4/config/certs/http_ca.crt -u elastic:*my elastic password* https://*adress*:9200 

Anybody had the same problem or has a solving idea?

Probably in the full log it mentions http_ca.crt location is wrong.
musab@musab-mac Desktop % curl --cacert elasticsearch-8.13.4/config/certs/http_ca.crt -u elastic:test https://localhost:9200

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:  CAfile: elasticsearch-8.13.4/config/certs/http_ca.crt CApath: none

Update the path and make sure http_ca.crt is there. You can check with ls command.
ls elasticsearch-8.13.4/config/certs/http_ca.crt

